# Force download a file within plugin file

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am trying to make a plugin which will force a certain file to download. I cannot find any examples of other people downloading files using a wordpress plug in. I simplified the code a little bit. I believe everything works until this part:

```
  header('Content-type: application/zip');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$destination.'"');
    echo readfile($destination);
    // remove zip file is exists in temp path
    unlink($destination);
```

Here is the code:

```
    function get_cart_urls(){
//get a string of urls from an ajax request

       $urlsCSV= $_POST['urlsCSV'];

//convert the string into an array
       $urlArray= explode(',', $urlsCSV);

        $destination = "Files.zip";
        $files = $urlArray;
        $overwrite = true;

            //if the zip file already exists and overwrite is false, return false
    if(file_exists($destination) && !$overwrite) { $error .= "yeha ";}
    //vars
    $valid_files = array();
    //if files were passed in...
    if(is_array($files)) {
        //cycle through each file
        foreach($files as $file) {
            //make sure the file exists
            if(file_exists(getcwd().$file)) {
                $valid_files[] = getcwd().$file;
            }
        }
    }
    //echo count($valid_files);
    //if we have good files...
    if(count($valid_files)) {
        //create the archive
        $zip = new ZipArchive();

        if($zip->open($destination,$overwrite ? ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE : ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== true) {
            $error = "yeah ";
        }else{
            $error = "no error";    
        }
        //add the files
        foreach($valid_files as $file) {
            $zip->addFile($file,$file);
        }
        //debug
        echo $error." ".'The zip archive contains ',$zip->numFiles,' files with a status of ',$zip->status;

        //close the zip -- done!
        $zip->close();


    if(file_exists($destination)){
            // push to download the zip
            header('Content-type: application/zip');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$destination.'"');
            echo readfile($destination);
            // remove zip file is exists in temp path
            unlink($destination);
        }
    die();
```

Comment: Is there a question somewhere? What about an actual problem description? And maybe some hints whether you are really using the code as is, especially with the debug `echo`. And finally, where exactly is this code being invoked?

Comment: I've used the plugin Customer Area which allows admins to upload files, and their users to download files. That could be an example (as you say you found none)

Comment: Can you make it work in general (without WP) for starters? This seems a little generic by itself so it's hard to guess how WP interacts with it, if at all.